# Use threads in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to use threads in this program, because it uses UI thread in current state.
I need other processes to use the UI thread while UI thread passes control to new created thread.

How to use thread structure in this code?

```
public class Ping extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
  Button pingButton;
  TextView pingText;
  EditText pingCommand;
  String address;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ping);
    pingButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPing);
    pingCommand = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tPingCommand);
    pingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tReturnResult);
    pingButton.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  public void ping() 
  {
    try {
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 8 " + address);
      BufferedReader reader = 
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
      int i;
      char[] buffer = new char[4096];
      StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
      while ((i = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.append(buffer, 0, i);
        pingText.setText(output);
      }
      reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    address = pingCommand.getText().toString();
    ping();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
public YourTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Object,Object>{ 

    protected void doInBackground(Object o){
        ping();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    address = pingCommand.getText().toString();
    // int packetNum = packetNumber.getId();
    // ping(address,packetNum);
    new YourTask().execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){ public void run(){
   try {
      address = pingCommand.getText().toString();
      int packetNum = packetNumber.getId();
      ping(address,packetNum);
      ping();
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      dialog.dismiss();
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
}).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // change UI elements here
        //ping()
    }
});
```